# jQuery: How to hide all HTML elements which have a value greater than a certain value for a given tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I display elements in a hierarchy, clicking one displays the next set of elements in the hirearchy. Each element has a tag called "level" which has some value which is 1-.... (whatever the number of levels is for that branch of the tree).

When an element is clicked I want the next elements to be displayed, but if an element is clicked and it's subelements have already been displayed I want to hide all subelements.

More formally:
 when an element with level = x is clicked
   if no elements with level > x are displayed 
     then display all elements such that level = x+1
   but if some elements with level > x are displayed
     then hide all elements where level > x

How would I create a jQuery selector that captures this.

Comment: Is the level inside a HTML tag or is it an attribute?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754021/jquery-get-a-list-of-values-of-an-attribute-from-elements-of-a-class ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of worrying about "level" attributes, why not just toggle visibility of all child elements of a certain type?  Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".treeNode").click(function() {
   $(this).children(".treeNode").toggle();
  });
});
```

I'm not sure of your architecture, but this would also keep the nodes in a different branch with the same "level" attribute from being toggled.