# jQuery - get a list of values of an attribute from elements of a class

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a class `.object` which has an attribute called `level`. I want to get a list of all the different values of `level` on the page so I can select the highest one.

If I do something like:

```
$(".object").attr("level")
```

... will that get me a list of values that are the values of the level attribute? I suspect not, but then how do you do something like that?

**Note:** I don't want to select an HTML object for manipulation as is more common, rather I want to select values of the attribute.

EDIT: In order to get the highest "level" I have done this, but it doesn't seem to work. I will try the other suggested method now.

```
var highLevel=0;
$.each(".object[level]", function(i, value) {
   if (value>highLevel) {
       highLevel=value;
   }
});

alert(highLevel);
```

Comment: @Ankur you should select one of these as the answer to this question

Answer (score 209):

`$(".object").attr("level")` will just return the attribute of first the first `.object` element.

This will get you an array of all `level`s:

```
var list = $(".object").map(function(){return $(this).attr("level");}).get();
```

Comment: What does the `.get()` do?

Comment: @Yuji - [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) converts the jQuery object to a regular array.

Comment: @MandeepJain: How does one mark an answer as 'correct'? This one may not have been marked as 'accepted', but over 100 people have voted it 'useful', and that's good enough for me!

Comment: Great answer.  A little more intuitive / cleaner for me is to `.get()` the array first, then use `.map()` plus arrow function (browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow) to build the array with a little plain javascript: `$(".object").get().map(x => x.getAttribute('level'));`

Answer (score 33):

First part of the question, getting the attribute values into an array.  See this question

[jQuery get img source attributes from list and push into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355025/jquery-get-img-source-attributes-from-list-and-push-into-array)

You would say

```
var levelArray = $('.object').map( function() {
    return $(this).attr('level');
}).get();
```

Second part of the question , you can use [this technique to get the highest value](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/)

```
var maxValue = Math.max.apply( Math, levelArray );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var max = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('.object[level]').each(function(){
        var num = parseInt($(this).attr('level'), 10);
        if (num > max) { max = num; }
    });
    alert(max);
});
</script>
```

I'm assuming markup like this:

```
<div class="object" level="1">placeholder</div>
<div class="object" level="10">placeholder</div>
<div class="object" level="20">placeholder</div>
<div class="object" level="1000">placeholder</div>
<div class="object" level="40">placeholder</div>
<div class="object" level="3">placeholder</div>
<div class="object" level="5">placeholder</div>
```

For my code I get "1000" alerted to me.

Here's another solution, combining several of the other replies from harpo, lomaxx, and Kobi:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    var list = $(".object[level]").map(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).attr("level"), 10);
    }).get();
    var max = Math.max.apply( Math, list ); 
    alert(max);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the selector

```
$(".object[level]")
```

will give you all the dom elements with class `object` and an attribute `level`.

Then you can just use the .each() method to iterate over the elements to get the highest value

Comment: `$(".object[level=something]")`  where something is what attribute value you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can [extend the functionality of Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) and add your own 'attrs' implementation.

Add the following lines of code to your JavaScript file:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    attrs: function (attributeName) {
        var results = [];
        $.each(this, function (i, item) {
            results.push(item.getAttribute(attributeName));
        });
        return results;
    }
});
```

Now you can get the list of level values by calling:

```
$(".object").attrs("level")
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery utility `$.map()` provides a cleaner approach that returns an array of values.

```js
let arr = $.map($('.object'), x => $(x).data('level'));

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="object" data-level="1">HTML5 technically does not require closing li tags</li>
  <li class="object" data-level="2">The Tidy function in SO code snippets do</li>
  <li class="object" data-level="3">*shrug*</li>
</ol>
```