# Get all checked checkboxes, possibly with same value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, jquery-ui-dialog, checked

I have prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afarber/6nddum4q/) for my question:

[image: screenshot]

In a word game I would like to display a dialog with all letter tiles in player's hand - and allow her to select some for swapping with the pile.

The letters are not unique, for example a player might have a hand "ABCDAB" as in the above screenshot - and select "ABA" for swapping.

Here is my code -

**HTML** (with dialog and button):

```
<div id="swapDlg" title="Swap letters">
  <p>Select letters for swapping:</p>
  <div id="swapList">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="swapBtn">Swap letters</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#swapDlg').dialog({
    modal: true,
    minWidth: 400,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
      'Swap': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        var result = 'How to get all selected letters?' // HERE
        alert('You would like to swap: ' + result);
      },
      'Cancel': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });

  $('#swapBtn').button().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#swapDlg').dialog('open');
  });

  var str = 'AB*CD*AB';
  var checkBoxes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var letter = str[i];
    if (letter != '*') {
      checkBoxes.push('<label><input type="checkbox" value="' +
        letter + '">&nbsp;' + letter + '</label>');
    }
  }

  $('#swapList')
    .empty()
    .append(checkBoxes.join('<br>'));
});
```

Please help me with the line marked by the `// HERE` comment.

How to get there the result as a string with all [checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop through checked element - create string from it and add in alertbox , Add this script:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9cdjjsL5/

```
    var a = [];
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        a.push($(this).val());
    });
    var str = a.join(', ');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.reduce`:

```
var result = $("#swapList :checked").toArray().reduce(function(acc, elt) {
     return acc + $(elt).val();
}, "");
```

ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vkfoxhh1/

Answer (score 2):

you want something like:

```
        var list = $(":checked").map(function(){return $(this).attr("value");}).get();
```

please note used top answer from: [jQuery - get a list of values of an attribute from elements of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754021/jquery-get-a-list-of-values-of-an-attribute-from-elements-of-a-class) to help me answer the question.

Fiddle (updated to use a join to convert array to string): http://jsfiddle.net/6nddum4q/5/

Comment: This would return an array, you'd still need a reduction operation (eg. `.join()`) to get a string

Comment: @blgt you are absolutely correct, here is the fiddle with a .join(""): [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nddum4q/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
        var result = [];
        $('#swapList input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                        result.push($(this).val());
                    });
        alert('You would like to swap: ' + result.join(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work checks out on your fiddle.

```
result = '';
$(function() {
  $('#swapDlg').dialog({
    modal: true,
    minWidth: 400,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
      'Swap': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        $('#swapList input:checked').each(function() {
          result += this.value;
          result += " ";
        });
        alert('You would like to swap: ' + result);
      },
      'Cancel': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
```